# hovertool displaying ??? for bokeh boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, boxplot

dataset: https://github.com/rashida048/Datasets/blob/master/StudentsPerformance.csv

I am trying to implement the hovertool function to display the value for the "Total" (sum of the 3 score columns) on each outlier. but when I hover over each value only ??? is displayed. I have also tried moving "source" inside the body of the function, as well as defining '@tot' in the hovertool as '@df.Total' and vice versa but still no success. where have I gone wrong? image attached.

[image]

```
source=ColumnDataSource(data=dict(df,tot=df.Total))

def box_plot(df, vals, label, ylabel=None,xlabel=None,title=None):
 
    # Group Data frame
    df_gb = df.groupby(label)
    # Get the categories
    cats = list(df_gb.groups.keys())

    # Compute quartiles for each group
    q1 = df_gb[vals].quantile(q=0.25)
    q2 = df_gb[vals].quantile(q=0.5)
    q3 = df_gb[vals].quantile(q=0.75)
                       
    # Compute interquartile region and upper and lower bounds for outliers
    iqr = q3 - q1
    upper_cutoff = q3 + 1.5*iqr
    lower_cutoff = q1 - 1.5*iqr

    # Find the outliers for each category
    def outliers(group):
        cat = group.name
        outlier_inds = (group[vals] > upper_cutoff[cat]) \
                                     | (group[vals] < lower_cutoff[cat])
        return group[vals][outlier_inds]

    # Apply outlier finder
    out = df_gb.apply(outliers).dropna()

    # Points of outliers for plotting
    outx = []
    outy = []
    for cat in cats:
        # only add outliers if they exist
        if cat in out and not out[cat].empty:
            for value in out[cat]:
                outx.append(cat)
                outy.append(value) 
                
    # If outliers, shrink whiskers to smallest and largest non-outlier
    qmin = df_gb[vals].min()
    qmax = df_gb[vals].max()
    upper = [min([x,y]) for (x,y) in zip(qmax, upper_cutoff)]
    lower = [max([x,y]) for (x,y) in zip(qmin, lower_cutoff)]

    cats = [str(i) for i in cats]
# Build figure
    p = figure(sizing_mode='stretch_width', x_range=cats,height=300,toolbar_location=None)
    p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
    p.ygrid.grid_line_width = 2
    p.yaxis.axis_label = ylabel
    p.xaxis.axis_label = xlabel
    p.title=title
    p.y_range.start=0
    p.title.align = 'center'
    
    # stems
    p.segment(cats, upper, cats, q3, line_width=2, line_color="black")
    p.segment(cats, lower, cats, q1, line_width=2, line_color="black")

    # boxes
    p.rect(cats, (q3 + q1)/2, 0.5, q3 - q1, fill_color=['#a50f15', '#de2d26', '#fb6a4a', '#fcae91', '#fee5d9'], 
           alpha=0.7, line_width=2, line_color="black")

    # median (almost-0 height rects simpler than segments)
    p.rect(cats, q2, 0.5, 0.01, line_color="black", line_width=2)

    # whiskers (almost-0 height rects simpler than segments)
    p.rect(cats, lower, 0.2, 0.01, line_color="black")
    p.rect(cats, upper, 0.2, 0.01, line_color="black")

    # outliers
    p.circle(outx, outy, size=6, color="black")
    
    p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[('Total','@tot')]))

    return p

p = box_plot(df, 'Total', 'race/ethnicity', ylabel='Total spread',xlabel='Race/Ethnicity',title='BoxPlot')
show(p)
```

```
the error i get after implementing your changes @mosc

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [18], in <cell line: 86>()
     82     p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[('Total','@tot')]))
     84     return p
---> 86 p = box_plot(df, 'Total', 'race/ethnicity', ylabel='Total spread',xlabel='Race/Ethnicity',title='BoxPlot')
     87 show(p)

Input In [18], in box_plot(df, vals, label, ylabel, xlabel, title)
     77 p.rect(cats, upper, 0.2, 0.01, line_color="black")
     79 # outliers
---> 80 p.circle(outx, outy, size=6, color="black", source=outliers_source)
     82 p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[('Total','@tot')]))
     84 return p

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\plotting\_decorators.py:86, in glyph_method.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs)
     84 if self.coordinates is not None:
     85     kwargs.setdefault("coordinates", self.coordinates)
---> 86 return create_renderer(glyphclass, self.plot, **kwargs)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\plotting\_renderer.py:96, in create_renderer(glyphclass, plot, **kwargs)
     94 incompatible_literal_spec_values += _process_sequence_literals(glyphclass, glyph_visuals, source, is_user_source)
     95 if incompatible_literal_spec_values:
---> 96     raise RuntimeError(_GLYPH_SOURCE_MSG % nice_join(incompatible_literal_spec_values, conjuction="and"))
     98 # handle the nonselection glyph, we always set one
     99 nonselection_visuals = pop_visuals(glyphclass, kwargs, prefix='nonselection_', defaults=glyph_visuals, override_defaults={'alpha':0.1})

RuntimeError: 

Expected x and y to reference fields in the supplied data source.

When a 'source' argument is passed to a glyph method, values that are sequences
(like lists or arrays) must come from references to data columns in the source.

For instance, as an example:

    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=a_list, y=an_array))

    p.circle(x='x', y='y', source=source, ...) # pass column names and a source

Alternatively, *all* data sequences may be provided as literals as long as a
source is *not* provided:

    p.circle(x=a_list, y=an_array, ...)  # pass actual sequences and no source
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you never pass a `source` to the figure object, but the `HoverTool` is looking for data in the `tot` column. There is none, and every time bokeh doesn't find any data, it shows `???`.

See the minimal example below, how it could work.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, ColumnDataSource
output_notebook()

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x=list(range(5)),
    y=list(range(5)),
    tot=list('ABCDE')
))

p = figure(width=300, height=300)
p.circle(x='x', y='y', source=source)
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[('Total','@tot')]))
show(p)
```

[image: simple HoverTool]

Back to your code and how to make a HoverTool work.
Since you only want a hover information for the outliers, you can create a `outliers_source` right befor you call `p.figure()`.

```
outliers_source= ColumnDataSource(dict(
    outx=outx,
    outy=outy,
    tot=list(range(len(outx)))
))
```

and then change the line below:

```
# old
# p.circle(outx, outy, size=6, color="black")
p.circle('outx', 'outy', size=6, color="black", source=outliers_source)
```

The changes maybe look quite small, but the information for the `circles` are now coming from a complete different source. Internally a lot has changed.

Now your HoverTool should show some numbers. You have to implement the logic of your information, because I didn't understand it.

Comment: thank you for the feedback, i have implemented the changes advised but i have received a runtime error. specified above

Comment: Did you change `outx` to `"outx"`? This is a shortcut for `x="outx"`. I think this is missing, because of this line in your error message: `p.circle(outx, outy, size=6, color="black", source=outliers_source)`.

Comment: yes i made the changes however the hover details are incorrect:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PDUg.png

Comment: Yes of course. I wrote in the last sentence of my answer, that I don't understand which values you want to show. I only explained how to activate the HoverTool. This time you have to figure it out by your own.

Comment: from the dataset linked above in the initial question, I am trying to display the values for a column I created as "Total" which is the sum of the other 3 "score" columns, and this "total" outlier is what I am trying to implement on the hover tool. this was all mentioned in the initial question

Comment: You did not show show you calculated 'Total'. Do you mean `df['Total'] = df['scor1'] +  df['score2`] + df['schore3']` is your data you want to show? The task is to get your "total" values into a list like "xout" and "yout" and pass it to your new `outliers_source`. Try to return in  `def outliers()`  `group[[val, 'Total']s][outlier_inds]` add a new list `totals = []` and then append to this list, if you append to `xout` and `yout`.